# Check if mobile network has disconnect a call

Tags: android, telephony

I wonder if it's possible to check if mobile network has disconnected a call, and thereby indicating the receiver is busy.

I've googled around like crazy but has not found any thing on this, so any example or help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use API telephony, check this [link](http://androidapps.org.ua/i_sect18_d1e18123.html) that provide examples.

Comment: I will give this one a go. I come with feedback when tested.

Answer (score 0):

Check out ServiceState class : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/ServiceState.html